# Help: Fatal error doing an export (Civi 4.7.4)

Tags: 4.7, export, drupal-6

I have just upgraded my Drupal 6 site to the latest CiviCRM 4.7.4 
All seemed to go well except that when I try to export contact records (using primary fields). I get the following fatal error:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ../public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php on line 435

Steps I followed:
1. Search for contacts
2. Select Export option
3. Select Export Primary fields
4. Press continue

Some help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks
Davy

Comment: This is a good question!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: I enabled the debug settings as suggested but still only get the one line error. No backtrace info at all. I cleared caches, switched off drupal caching, cleared Civi caches, deleted content of templates_c directory, tried in Chrome and Safari... but still only the one line. :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 435 in CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php that your error message is referring to says:

```
if (!empty(self::defaultReturnProperty($exportMode))) {
```

This will give an error in all PHP versions below 5.5. From the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error

You should be able to fix this by replacing lines 435-437 in Export.php with something like

```
  $key = self::defaultReturnProperty($exportMode);
  if ($key) {
    $returnProperties[$key] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: Yes!  That fixed it. Thanks very much for your help. :-)  :-)

Comment: I keep running afoul of this because my laptop has a later version of PHP than my live server.

Comment: Should this be considered a bug?  Is it already set up?

Comment: I have reported this in the CiviCRM issue queue at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18279 so it will hopefully be fixed in the next version.